# Existence of special enumeration of the rationals

Tags: real-analysis, rational-numbers

I am looking for an enumeration of $\mathbb Q$ which has a specific property. It is inspired by Problem 4.13(ii)(b) from the book Measures, Integrals and Martingales by René L. Schilling (second edition).

Let $q_1,q_2,\dots$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb Q$. For all $\epsilon>0$, let $$C(\epsilon):=\cup_{n\in\mathbb N}[q_n-\epsilon2^{-n},q_n+\epsilon2^{-n}).$$ Let $C:=\cap_{\epsilon>0}C(\epsilon)$. Now clearly $\mathbb Q\subseteq C$. Is it possible to find an enumeration such that $\mathbb Q=C$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Νο.

Note that $\bigcap_{\epsilon>0}^{\infty}C(\epsilon)=\bigcap_{m=1}^{\infty}C(\frac{1}{m})$

So you would have that $$\Bbb{Q}\subseteq\bigcap_{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(q_n-\frac{1}{2^nm},q_n+\frac{1}{2^nm}) \subseteq C=\Bbb{Q}$$

So $\Bbb{Q}$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set which contradicts  Baire's Category Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(q_n)$ be any enumeration of the rationals.  Now define closed intervals $[a_n, b_n]$ with the following properties:  $[a_n, b_n] \subseteq C(1/n)$, $q_n \notin [a_n, b_n]$, and $[a_{n+1}, b_{n+1}] \subseteq [a_n, b_n]$.  Then $\bigcap_n [a_n, b_n]$ is nonempty, it is contained in $C$, and it is disjoint from $\mathbb{Q}$.  So no such enumeration can exist.

Comment: Once you have defined $[a_n,b_n]$, it could be that $[a_n,b_n]$ is not a subset of $C(1/(n+1))$. In some cases, $[a_n,b_n]$ and $C(1/(n+1))$ could even be disjoint. Then you can’t define $[a_{n+1},b_{n+1}]$. Could you add details for how you chose the intervals?

Comment: Assuming $a_n < b_n$ (perhaps I should have specified that), the interval $(a_n, b_n)$ will contain infinitely many rational numbers.  Pick a rational $q \ne q_{n+1}$ such that $a_n < q < b_n$.  Now let $[a_{n+1}, b_{n+1}]$ be an interval centered at $q$ that is small enough that (1) it is contained in $[a_n, b_n]$, (2) it does not contain $q_{n+1}$, and (3) it is contained in $C(1/(n+1))$.  (The last condition is possible because $C(1/(n+1))$ contains an interval centered at $q$.)

Comment: Thank you, that’s correct!